# Как правильно перебрать массив для записи в csv

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, csv

есть массив

```
array(2)
{
    array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["from"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["to"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["subject_one"]=>
      string(44) "Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
      ["subject_two"]=>
      string(122) "Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date_email_sent"]=>
      string(37) "Date: Wed,  6 Feb 2019 18:01:28 +0800"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date_email_parse"]=>
      string(19) "2019-02-15 09:46:16"
    }
  }
  array(28) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(21) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(21) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [11]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [12]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(18) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [13]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [14]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [15]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [16]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [17]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [18]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [19]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(15) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [20]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [21]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(18) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [22]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "email@test.com"
      ["signature"]=>
      string(29) "Host or domain name not found"
    }
    [23]=>
    array(1) {
      ["from"]=>
      string(17) "email@test.com"
    }
    [24]=>
    array(1) {
      ["to"]=>
      string(21) "email@test.com"
    }
    [25]=>
    array(2) {
      ["subject_one"]=>
      string(44) "Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
      ["subject_two"]=>
      string(175) "Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
    }
    [26]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date_email_sent"]=>
      string(37) "Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2018 17:36:18 +0800"
    }
    [27]=>
    array(1) {
      ["date_email_parse"]=>
      string(19) "2019-02-15 09:46:20"
    }
  }
}
```

как его перебрать что бы записать в csv в следующем виде, то-есть в массиве есть вложенные массивы, в первом вложенном есть email и signature их может быть n-ое кол-во, а вот всего остального в по одному, если email/signature повторяются больше одного раза, то их нужно как то сгруппировать и добавить к ним их описание from, to, subject_one, subject_two, date_email_sent, date_email_parse

[image: пример]

Comment: Описали бы структуру массива тогда. У вас там N элементов, каждый из которых массив. В мелком массиве сначала идут M-объектов, содержащих email/sig и затем остатки с доп. инфой. Вам надо раписать каждый вложенный объект в M строк? Или там там только к в первой строке дописать

Comment: @teran спасибо за комментарий, но разве в тексте не описан массив? если это не правильно, подскажите как описать структуру массива? По сути надо в первые два столбца записать email/sig, а затем доп инфу. посмотрите рисунок пожалуйста.

Comment: описать - в смысле словами русскими сказать, что именно сделать, в случае когда email/sig больше чем один.

Comment: @teran добавил более полное описание, спасибо.

Comment: дак если этих email/sig несколько, то добавить надо только к первому? на картинке поэтому пропуски? откуда вы вообще получаете такой ущербный массив?

Comment: @teran ну да, только к первому. паршу емейлы =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем хотелось чего то изящного, но ваш последний элемент с subject все портит :D

исходные:

```
$data = [
    [['email' => 'email1', 'sig' => 'sig1'],.
     ['from' => 'from1'], ['to' => 'to1'], ['sOne' => 's11' , 'sTwo' => 's12']],

    [['email' => 'email2', 'sig' => 'sig2'],.
     ['email' => 'email3', 'sig' => 'sig3'],
     ['email' => 'email4', 'sig' => 'sig4'],
     ['from' => 'from2'], ['to' => 'to2'], ['sOne' => 's21' , 'sTwo' => 's22']],
];
```

и дальше обход массива. каждая первая пара email/sig с доп. сведенями, остальные без доп. сведений.

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $d){
    [$from, $to, $s] = array_splice($d, count($d) - 3);

    $first = array_shift($d);
    $result[] = $first +  $from + $to + $s;

    $result = array_merge($result, $d);
}

$f = fopen("./data/csv.csv", "w");
foreach($result as $l){
    fputcsv($f, $l);
}
```

^на выходе

```
email1,sig1,from1,to1,s11,s12
email2,sig2,from2,to2,s21,s22
email3,sig3
email4,sig4
```

Comment: я могу исправить проблему с subject_one/two и записать их идентично from, to и тд

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev если вы можете исправить, то не ясно с какой вообще целью вы в таком виде сформировали этот массив, чтобы потом мучаться, как его записаться в файл.

Comment: к сожалению не получалось записать иначе в рамках одного цикла, ну или я не достаточно опытен в этом

Comment: я немного изменил код, он записывает так как надо, но если встречается большое кол-во email/signature, то происходит PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: [0-5] in /var/www/html/www/tagline-msg-parser/messages-parser.php on line 317, где [0-5] - может быть от нуля до пяти. Подскажите как избавится от этого?

Comment: все поправил, спасибо!